# how to add an object to a script tag with document.body.appendChild

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

I have a site that's written in asp.net MVC that I'm trying to replicate with React

in some page i have this script tag:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="https://some.url.that.returns.an.object.com">
            {
                loginURL: 'http//:blahBlah/login',
                logoutURL: 'http://blahBlah/Logout'
            }
    </script>
}
```

so far I managed to create the script tag on that specific page, but i dont know how to add that loginUrl and logoutUrl

made it with this code:

```
useEffect(() => {

    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = `https://some.url.that.returns.an.object.com`
    script.async = true
    script.onload = () => scriptLoaded()

    document.body.appendChild(script)
  })
```

how can I add those urls?

my app is written with ReactJS, is there any way in React that i can do it better?

thanks

Comment: React is (generally) client-side and ASP.NET MVC is server-side - so why can't you just combine the two systems rather than reimplementing the ASP.NET MVC logic in React?

Comment: @Dai - I believe the ASP.Net code shown just sets up a script tag to be output client-side, rather than actually doing something itself.

Comment: `<script>` elements **cannot** have both `src=""` and an inner script set - so the code you've posted simply won't work. If you mean that the `<script>` element *only* has a `src=""` attribute and the contents of that downloaded script are the `{ loginURL, logoutURL }` object then please rephrase your question.

Comment: @Dai - Yes, they can. The text within the tags is "documentation" for the script; [details](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element) *(see "Content Model").* Some libs do this where you provide configuration information within the script tag that loads them. But I take your point that the name given in `src` suggests that it *could* be returning that text; could definitely use clarification by the OP...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Huh, TIL! [Thank you!](https://xkcd.com/1053/) When was this change made? (Annoyingly, WHATWG uses a single file for the Living Standard which is now too huge for `git blame` to work... )

Comment: @Dai - I think it's always been that way. [HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT) says that browsers should "ignore" text within the element if `src` is present, which is of course slightly different. I became aware of the "documentation" interpretation of that text no later than 2008. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the text content of a `script` tag, you use `textContent` (or `innerText` for obsolete browsers):

```
const script = document.createElement('script')
script.src = `https://some.url.that.returns.an.object.com`
script.textContent = `{
            loginURL: 'http//:blahBlah/login',
            logoutURL: 'http://blahBlah/Logout'
        }`;
script.async = true
script.onload = () => scriptLoaded()
```

**But:**

1. When you have text within a `script` tag **and** the `script` tag has a `src`, the text within it is just "documentation." It's possible that the script being referred to by the `src` can figure out what `script` tag it's being loaded from and can use that content, but the way it does that may not work if you're creating the script dynamically.
2. This is unlikely to be the way you want to do this in a React project. In React, you almost never want to directly manipulate the DOM. It does come up sometimes, but in general, you try to avoid it.

Comment: Judging by the majority of ASP.NET devs I've come across (including myself!), I'm going to assume the content of the `<script>` element was not intended to be documentation ;)

Comment: this actually works! thank you, of course this isn't how i usually use with react, but thats a specific case in my work that has to be done this way unfortunately, can you suggest another way for me to include this script in a specific component?

Comment: @DorLugasi-Gal - It would depend on the script. If it requires that inline content, then...